# Sorting a 2D vector with specific criteria using std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, 2d

I have encountered one coding problem regarding sorting a 2D vector (matrix) using a desired criteria using `std::sort` from library `algorithm`

For example let's say I have a 2D vector

```
1,8,3
1,9,1
1,4,2 
    ^
```

and I want to sort it by 3rd column (for example growth criteria) 
So after sorting I want to have a matrix:

```
1,9,1
1,4,2
1,8,3
    ^
```

I know that in order to specify sorting criteria in `std::sort`, third function needs to be sent in `std::sort`. If it were a 1D `vector` it would not be a problem. I would make a lambda inside `std::sort` with 2 parameters, compare them and return true/false.

So now you can see the problem I am facing, how can I access specific elements inside a matrix, in my case third column elements and compare them with `std::sort`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void printMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<int>> m) {
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m[i].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m{
        {1,8,3},
        {1,9,1},
        {1,4,2}
    };

    std::sort(m.begin(), m.end(), [](int a, int b) { // error
                // ???
    });
    printMatrix(m);

    return 0;
}
```

I would not like to use any other external libraries to solve this problem.

Any help is very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::sort(m.begin(), m.end(), [](int a, int b) { // error
                // ???
    });
```

The `value_type` of the iterators returned by `m.begin()` and `m.end()` is a `std::vector<int>`. Hence, your lambda needs to take that *type* for both of its parameters.

```
std::sort(m.begin(), m.end(), 
        [](const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b) {
               return a.at(2) < b.at(2);
    });
```

Note: I am using the `at()` member function here rather than operator `[]` to prevent UB should you ever mistakenly attempt to sort by in invalid index.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8606c30c4b99905)

Comment: Thanks! The solution is simpler than I thought it would be! :)

Comment: @galaxyworks. You are welcome. Anytime! I'm glad this solves your problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you want to sort a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, the items of the container are of type `std::vector<int>`, not `int`. Hence, you cannot use a `lambda` with the declaration

```
[](int a, int b) { ... }
```

to sort such a container. You need to use a `lambda` with the declaration

```
[](std::vector<int> a, std::vector<int> b) { ... }
```

or

```
[](std::vector<int> const& a, std::vector<int> const& b) { ... }
```

Using the first version is expensive since it will end up making copies of `std::vector` for each call to the `lambda`. Hence, it is recommended to use the second version.

```
std::sort(m.begin(), m.end(), [](std::vector<int> const& a,
                                 std::vector<int> const& b) {
   return a.back() < b.back();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not the most efficient solution, the simplest thing to do would be to transpose your 2D vector (aka matrix) sort each vector and then transpose again. Here is a tested, working function that will do this for you:

```
template<typename T>
void sortColumns(vector<vector<T> > &v){
    vector<vector<T> > rv(v[0].size(), vector<T>(v.size()));
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++){
            rv[j][i] = v[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rv.size(); i++){
        sort(rv[i].begin(), rv[i].end());
        for(int j = 0; j < rv[i].size(); j++){
            v[j][i] = rv[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Again this isn't the most efficient or the most modern way to sort a matrix by columns but it works and is simple to understand.